# Python - sort lists of lists containing tuples in place

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can i sort a list which looks like this by the 2. tuple element ascending:

```
list = [[('A',4),('B',2),('C',7)],[('A',5),('B',1),('C',9)]]
```

to look like this (inplace):

```
list = [[('B',2),('A',4),('C',7)],[('B',1),('A',5),('C',9)]]
```

Sorting with

```
sorted(list, key=lambda entry: entry[1], reverse=False)
```

isn't working because i don't know how to "access" the second (inner) list in my lambda function

Comment: On what criteria are the nested lists reordered?

Comment: If a lambda can't do it, just use a separate function and refer to that

Comment: I'm confused what this is doing. Tuples are immutable, so `(2,1)`->`(1,2)` isn't possible in-place.

Comment: the nested list have to stay in this order. just the contained tuples should be ordered

Comment: So you're sorting on the second element in the tuple?

Comment: Here, `entry` is a list, so `entry[1]` is the second tuple in each list.

Comment: Yes sry my example was kind of confusing. i changed the first tuple value to a char

Comment: Please edit your question and provide step-by-step for one of the inner lists what you want to do. It seems like you want to keep the first element of each tuple to stay where it is but sort the second element of each tuple.

Comment: No sry, i fixed my example.

Comment: Ok, now I get it :-) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sort()` method on a list to sort it in place.  For your example:

```
for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list.sort(key=lambda entry: entry[1])
```

or equivalently, but slightly faster

```
for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working inplace for my_list   if i print sub_list it is sorted correctly but when i print my_list nothing has changed.

Comment: just a guess, but is sub_list a SLICE  of my_list.  if so, it is actually creating a new copy of the elements in the slice and then sorting that.  that's why my_list isn't being sorted in place

Comment: @JH: The code above does change the lists in place, see https://ideone.com/TpzyWe.  If it doesn't work for you, you are doing something different, but we will only be able to figure out what it is you are doing if you show us your code.